# Adjust Input.GetAxis To Face Player Axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am learning Unity and using the tutorials for [Evac City](http://www.rebelplanetcreations.com/downloads/Other/Tutorials/HowToMakeAGameInUnity3D.pdf)  with version 4.3. This sample is a top down 2D shooter that uses the mouse for rotation and the keyboard for movement using the arrows or WASD keys.

One thing that I was trying and not having much luck with was with changing the orientation of the movement. I would like the keyboard movement to be relative to the the direction of the player instead of to the world plane so that the W key will move you forward in the direction you are facing, the S key moves you back, the A key slides you left and the D keys slides you right.

The relevant parts of the code seem to be:

```
   void FindPlayerInput()
{
    // find vector to move
    inputMovement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));

    // find vector to the mouse
    tempVector2 = new Vector3(Screen.width * 0.5f, 0, Screen.height * 0.5f); // the position of the middle of the screen
    tempVector = Input.mousePosition; // find the position of the moue on screen
    tempVector.z = tempVector.y; // input mouse position gives us 2D coordinates, I am moving the Y coordinate to the Z coorindate in temp Vector and setting the Y coordinate to 0, so that the Vector will read the input along the X (left and right of screen) and Z (up and down screen) axis, and not the X and Y (in and out of screen) axis
    tempVector.y = 0;
    inputRotation = tempVector - tempVector2; // the direction we want face/aim/shoot is from the middle of the screen to where the mouse is pointing
}

void ProcessMovement()
{
    tempVector = rigidbody.GetPointVelocity(transform.position) * Time.deltaTime * 1000;
    rigidbody.AddForce(-tempVector.x, -tempVector.y, -tempVector.z);
    rigidbody.AddForce(inputMovement.normalized * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(inputRotation);
    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, transform.eulerAngles.y + 180, 0);
    print("x:" + transform.eulerAngles.x + " y:" + transform.eulerAngles.y + " z:" + transform.eulerAngles.z);

    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, 0, transform.position.z);
}
```

I have tried a few different things and recognize that the Input.GetAxis calls come from the keyboard mappings but not how to re-orient the movement to the player axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is transform the input direction from the player's local space to world space, to put it in the good-to-know "space" terminology. You can do this with [`Transform.TransformDirection`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformDirection.html):

```
Vector3 worldInputMovement = transform.TransformDirection(inputMovement.normalized);
rigidbody.AddForce(worldInputMovement * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

This works because `TransformDirection` will rotate the vector you give it to put it in world space, and `AddForce` expects a world-space vector.

Comment: Thanks. That is working for my player movement. It has some side effects for the enemy movement that I still need to overcome but gets me going in the right direction (so to speak...).

Comment: Odd that it would affect enemy movement, but I guess I don't have the full context. Maybe transforming as you set the input rather than when you apply the input would do it: i.e. at `inputMovement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), ...`, since I'm assuming that isn't shared but `ProcessMovement` is.